# Get Substring and Use it In Where Clause

Tags: sql-server

how can I get substring from scanfields (6400,6401,6402) and store it in a variable then use it in a where clause later on? I am trying to get all unique rows that have that substring in the scanfield column.

table 1

```
scanfields           amount
/411500640036800      50.00
/411500640036800      50.00
/411500640136800      60.00
/411500640236800       70.00
```

select disintct * from table1 where scanfields = *variable goes here*

results

```
scanfields           amount
/411500640036800      50.00
/411500640136800      60.00
/411500640236800       70.00
```

Comment: While asking a question, you need to provide a **minimal reproducible example**. Please refer to the following link:
https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example
Please provide the following:  
(1) DDL and sample data population, i.e. CREATE table(s) plus INSERT T-SQL statements. 
(2) What you need to do, i.e. logic and your code attempt implementation of it in T-SQL. 
(3) Desired output, based on the sample data in #1 above.
(4) Your SQL Server version (SELECT @@version;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
select * 
from [Table2]
where scanfields IN (SELECT substring(scanfields, 7,4) from [Table 1])
```

Note this will tend to be slow. If you have a field like this, where you know portions of the value are distinct elements in advance, you will do **much better** splitting up the elements as separate fields in the table, so you can index them. Failing that, you can set up a [Computed Column](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/tables/specify-computed-columns-in-a-table?view=sql-server-ver15), which can also be indexed.

Comment: is there anyway to get only distinct value. See my edited post. Now I have returns 3 rows instead of 4.

Comment: since all the other fields match up, you can say `select distinct * from table1`, with no where clause. If any of the other fields _don't_ match up, you need to tell us more about what you want to show.